# Loop through sheets creating graphs

Tags: excel, vba

Im setting up a workbook that needs weekly updates. 
It contains 10 sheets and im trying to create a loop that makes a graph for each sheet.

I tryed a loop with sh.activate, that ended up creating a graph with the data from worksheet1 in all the worksheets.
After this i tried to create a look without .activate it doenst work though
Is this the correct way to do it?

```
Sub graph()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim StartCell As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set StartCell = .Range("e1")
        Set chrt = .Shapes.AddChart.Chart

        With chrt
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range("$C$1:$D$11")
            .ChartType = xlLine

            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = .Range("$F$1")
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = .Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = .Range("E2:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .SeriesCollection(2).Name = .Range("$E$1")
            .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = .Range("E2:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .SeriesCollection(2).Values = .Range("F2:F" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Effektivitet"
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: All of these dot notations and no with statement to support them... for each ws in Worksheets, then you need to specify that you're working with ws, that way shapes and the sort are qualified to that specific sheet, not using activate.  Note that you have StartCell using .Range, but you have not specified a worksheet for that range to exist.

Comment: Alright, im new still to vba, so i apreciate the help. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define in which worksheet these `Range` and `Shape` objects are. Eg in

```
Set StartCell = .Range("e1")
Set chrt = .Shapes.AddChart.Chart
```

define `ws` as worksheet:

```
Set StartCell = ws.Range("e1")
Set chrt = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
```

Note that statements can only begin with a dot `.Range` if they are within a `With` statement. So the above is the same as the following:

```
With ws
    Set StartCell = .Range("e1")
    Set chrt = .Shapes.AddChart.Chart
End With
```

You also need to check your other range objects because they start like `.Range("$F$1")` they refer to `With chrt` which is a chart object but they should refer to `ws.Range("$F$1")`.

So you should end up with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub graph()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim StartCell As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set StartCell = ws.Range("e1")
        Set chrt = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

        With chrt
            .SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("$C$1:$D$11")
            .ChartType = xlLine

            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = ws.Range("$F$1")
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws.Range("E2:E" & ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .SeriesCollection(2).Name = ws.Range("$E$1")
            .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = ws.Range("E2:E" & ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .SeriesCollection(2).Values = ws.Range("F2:F" & ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Effektivitet"
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This works thank you very i really apprecite the help!