# Loop through multiple sheets and make embedded graphs

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing the graphs as described in the following post
[Loop through sheets creating graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338360/loop-through-sheets-creating-graphs)
But i face the problem while using the code below

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub graph()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim StartCell As Range
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set StartCell = ws.Range("e1")
        Set chrt = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

        With chrt
            .SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("$A$1:$A$45, $D$1:$D$45, $E$1:$E$45")
            .ChartType = xlLine

            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = ws.Range("$D$1")
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws.Range("D2:D" & ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .SeriesCollection(2).Name = ws.Range("$E$1")
            .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .SeriesCollection(2).Values = ws.Range("E2:E" & ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

            '.HasTitle = True
            '.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Effektivitet"
        End With
    Next ws End Sub
```

It makes line chart but with the double line/series of E.

Comment: I think you need to change this: `.ChartType = xlLine` to what type of line you want.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcharttype Easiest way would be using the macro recorder to manually set the style you want, and then check the code and get the value you need for `ChartType`

Comment: Chart type is the line chart. It is not the problem. Problem is that instead of having two series i have 3 series/line

Answer (score 1):

It has been solved. I am making mistake here

```
    With chrt
        .SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("$C$1:$D$11")
        .ChartType = xlLine
```